# Map the Array in to the each individual JSON so the records can be created

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to convert the below Array in to the JSON, trying by iterating through the Array and transforming. The array looks like below

```
Quote_Sent_To__r = [
{
Quote__c=0Q02D05XGQSA2,
 Id=a1H2D0m94QUAQ, 
type=QuoteSentTo__c
},
{
Quote__c=0Q02D00XGQSA2,
 Id=a1H2D00000AQ, 
type=QuoteSentTo__c
}
]
```

I have stored the array in to the variable quoteSentToList and iterating through the for loop

[image]

Within each iteration I need to get the JSON like

```
   {
    "Quote__c": "0Q02D05XGQSA2"
    }
```

So this can be passed to the Salesforce Update operation. I tried like

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var item = vars.quoteSentToList[counter]
---
{
"Quote__c" :payload.Id
}
```

It errors saying

`Reason: Unable to resolve reference of:` counter`..`
`Scripting language error on expression 'payload'. Reason: Unable to resolve reference of:` payload`..`
This is my first project and any help is greatly appreciated

Error

`""Unexpected character 'v' at quoteSentToList@[1:1] (line:column), expected false or true or null or {...} or [...] or number but was , while reading` quoteSentToList `as Json.`

`1| vars.existingQuote[0].Quote_Sent_To__r ^" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0 output application/json`
`---`
`vars.quoteSentToList map {  Quote__c: payload.Id, Id: $.Id     }"."`

Comment: Counter is a variable so is accessed as `vars.counter`.  However, as the foreach scope iterates over the collection, it sets the payload to the current object in the collection, so you shouldn't need to set the variable `item`.

Comment: @Jesse0451 you should write that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: It looks like your variable doesn't has the right media type. DataWeave is trying to parse it as JSON but it doesn't has the right format. Please add the flow as text escaped as codeblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter` is a Mule variable, not a DataWeave variable. You need to use the prefix `vars.` to reference it inside DataWeave scripts: `vars.counter`.

Alternatively, instead of using a `<foreach>` scope, you can transform the entire array at once and then use each element as needed:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
vars.quoteSentToList map { Quote__c: $.Id }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Quote__c": "a1H2D0m94QUAQ"
  },
  {
    "Quote__c": "a1H2D00000AQ"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. But I am getting error like Auto-Coercing type from: `Any` to: `Null`.

Comment: Updated the question with the error I am seeing

Comment: Your variable apparently doesn't has the right format type set. It is being parsed as JSON when it is not JSON. It may be related to how the variable was set previously.